# How to change the Google App Engine SDK location in Eclipse Neon.3?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have installed the latest Google Cloud SDK (200.0.0) and Google Cloud Tools on Eclipse Neon.3. The GCloud App Java Extensions have also been installed as below.

[image]

It seems the latest Google App Engine SDK 1.9.63 has been installed at:
C:\Users{USERNAME}.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.63

According to Google App Engine online documentation, I had to download and unzip the SDK (appengine-java-sdk-1.9.63) to a different directory.

I would like to use the SDK that I downloaded but the one in Maven. How can I change the location of the installed Google App Engine SDK in Eclipse?

EDIT:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify a few things:

- `.m2\repository` is where Maven customarily caches Maven artifacts. Whenever any Maven projects make use of any JARs, they will generally be cached in that local repository. Since it is just a cache, you can safely delete the repository anytime in general. `mvn package`, for example, will download and cache necessary JARs again.
- That said, `.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.63` just contains a cached JAR: `appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.6.3-jar`. Certainly, you wouldn't call a single JAR "Software Development Kit (SDK)"; I would call it, if I have to, an App Engine API JAR. Also, the JAR might have been cached by someone else than "Google Cloud SDK"; any Maven project that makes use of the classes in the JAR would automatically cache it.
- "Cloud SDK" is a collection of tools and libraries for Google Cloud development and management.
- "App Engine SDK for Java" as in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download is another, different collection of tools and libraries for App Engine Java development, which you won't probably need here. The SDK is separate and independent from the Cloud SDK.
- You don't need to download "App Engine SDK for Java" when using "Cloud Tools for Eclipse" (CT4E). CT4E is Cloud SDK-based and not App Engine SDK-based. Why do you need to manually download the App Engine API JAR? For example, you can add the JAR to your project in Eclipse by *Preferences* > *Java Build Path* > *Libraries* > *Add Library* > *Google Cloud Platform Libraries* > *App Engine API* > *Finish*.

Comment: Thanks @Chanseok! This really helped me with a better understanding of GAE. The GAE Standard Java project I am working with uses a App Engine Standard Runtime library by default. It only contains the servlet api and jsp api jar files. I didn't include the App Engine API as you instructed but the project still compiled and ran without an issue. The App Engine SDK jar file was not referenced anywhere in the project structure. Are the servlet and jsp api jar files sufficient for an App Engine project to run? See attached screenshots please. This is confusing me.

Comment: So far, you are not using any App Engine API, so yeah, you don't need to add App Engine API. If you find yourself needing to call some API from it to achieve some App Engine-specific task, that's when you'll certainly know you have to add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure App Engine SDK in Eclipse, you can just configure Google Cloud SDK inside Eclipse Google Cloud Tools.

Google App Engine SDK is a component of the Google Cloud SDK {1} so you can install it this way:

```
gcloud components install [COMPONENT-ID]
```

If you are using Java, `[COMPONENT-ID]` would be `app-engine-java`.

Good luck!

{1}: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components

Comment: Thanks @J.L Valtueña. There is one thing I am not quite clear that, it seems not sensible to download and install the Google App Engine SDK separately if the Google Cloud SDK already contains the App Engine SDK. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download Is this duplicated work for development?